# Annotation tool working with IE7

Tags: javascript, annotations, internet-explorer-7

I am using http://annotateit.org/ in order to be able to let other people annotate a website.
Does anyone knows how to make it work with IE7?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is a limitation - there are much nicer annotation plugins out there which DO support IE though...

Comment: thanks. Do you have any recommendation?